# How to do a group by using Java

Tags: java

Goal:
Make a group by for the datamember _age and then _amount by using java

The result should be:

```
age      amount
---------------
  0           8
  1           8
  2           8
  3           8
```

Problem:
I was not expected that it would be more difficult to do it in java compare to C#

Based on the inspiration from this [page](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/) I was trying to make group by but it didn't work.

What part am I missing

Thank you!

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JavaApplication22 
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Test> _Test = new ArrayList<>();
        _Test.add(new Test(0, "df", 4));
        _Test.add(new Test(0, "we", 4));
        _Test.add(new Test(1, "df", 4));
        _Test.add(new Test(1, "we", 4));
        _Test.add(new Test(2, "df", 4));
        _Test.add(new Test(2, "we", 4));
        _Test.add(new Test(3, "df", 4));
        _Test.add(new Test(3, "we", 4));


        // This one below is error
        Map<String, Integer> sum = _Test.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::get, Collectors.summarizingInt(Test::get)));


    }

}
```

---

```
public class Test
{
    private int _age;
    private String _sex;
    private int _amount;

    public Test(int age, String sex, int amount)
    {
        _age = age;
        _sex = sex;
        _amount = amount;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return _age;
    }    

    public String getSex(String sex)
    {
        return _sex;
    }     

    public int getAmount()
    {
        return _amount;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please explain ["but it didn't work"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: I tried changing into summingInt and also adding the method "getAge" but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems in your code.

1. For mapping

   ```
   age      amount
   ---------------
     0           8
     1           8
     2           8
     3           8
   ```

   better suited type would be `Map<Integer, Integer>` instead of `Map<String, Integer>`.
2. `Collectors.summarizingInt` will produce `IntSummaryStatistics`. To get only sum of integers use `Collectors.summingInt`.
3. There is no `get` method in Test class. You need to be more specific if you want to use `getAge` or `getSex` or `getAmount`.

So you probably are looking for:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> sum = _Test //<- type of key should be Integer, not String
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Test::getAge, // <- grouping by age
                Collectors.summingInt(Test::getAmount) //<-use summingInt instead of summarizingInt
                                                       //  to sum amount attribute
            )
        );
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using a map would be a better approach. Using the Age as the key which corresponds to a counter. If the key exists increment the counter, otherwise insert the key and initiate the counter at 1.